# How to get post meta (advance custom field) in JSON of custom post type

Tags: php, json, wordpress

Its bit annoying to to get post meta in JSON of custom post type. I am using "json-api" plugin but it is not providing to fetch all post metas of all posts for specific post type.

For post meta I have used "Advance custom field" plugin.

My client wants to get all post meta of all posts of particular post type.

Please guide me.

Thanks

Comment: you need to edit `json-api` plugin's file.

Comment: Thanks, Ya I customized plugin but still not that sure, But for now It already sent for testing. I have edited code to get all post meta of specific custom post type, It is working but lets see if client get satisfied or not :)